# Paint on JPanel without redrawing background image

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel, paint

I'm trying to make a screenshot tool that shows screenshot picture to user in fullscreen. Then user will edit it with a few tools.
While creating it, i faced a problem with visualization of some effects. 
I want to create visual representation of selected area using selection rectangle(don't know the exact term name) that you use to select multiple files on desktop or file explorer. [example image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKV9Y.png)

I tried to do it with drawing rectangle on background picture, but when i tried to move a cursor, image was refreshing ugly.
Then I tried to do transparent panel with both `setOpaque(false);` and `setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));` and than pin mouse listeners on this panel. 
It draws rectangle successfully, but background of panel instantly fills with default grey color.
How can i make foreground panel transparent and draw something on it, without repainting background image?
Here is my Glass class:

```
private static final int WIDE = 1920;
private static final int HIGH = 1080;
private final Color clean = new Color(0,0,0,0);
private Point mousePt = new Point(WIDE / 2, HIGH / 2);
private Rectangle mouseRect = new Rectangle();


Glass(){
    this.setOpaque(false);
    this.setBackground(clean);
    this.addMouseListener(new MouseHandler());
    this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionHandler());
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {  
    g.setColor(clean);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 1920, 1080 );
    g.setColor(Color.darkGray);
    g.drawRect(mouseRect.x, mouseRect.y, mouseRect.width, mouseRect.height);
}
private class MouseHandler extends MouseAdapter {

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("released");
        mouseRect.setBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
        e.getComponent().repaint();
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        mousePt = e.getPoint();
        System.out.println("pressed");
        e.getComponent().repaint();
    }
}
private class MouseMotionHandler extends MouseMotionAdapter {
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
         mouseRect.setBounds(
              Math.min(mousePt.x, e.getX()),
              Math.min(mousePt.y, e.getY()),
              Math.abs(mousePt.x - e.getX()),
              Math.abs(mousePt.y - e.getY())); 
        e.getComponent().repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried adding `super.paintComponent(g)` to the beginning of your paintComponent method like so:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(clean);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 1920, 1080 );
    g.setColor(Color.darkGray);
    g.drawRect(mouseRect.x, mouseRect.y, mouseRect.width, mouseRect.height);
}
```

Another possibility would be to use a JPanel for all of your drawing and just draw the background image in your paintComponent method too:

```
class DrawPanel extends JPanel{
    public DrawPanel(){
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        //Draw background
        g.drawImage(yourImage, 0, 0);

        //Your drawing
        g.setColor(Color.darkGray);
        g.drawRect(mouseRect.x, mouseRect.y, mouseRect.width, mouseRect.height);
    }
}
```

Using a JPanel instead of a `java.awt.Panel` will use double-buffering and avoid any flickering while drawing.

Your code of the parent-container could look like:

```
public MainFrame(){
    //...

    //Your old code
    //background image...
    //getContentPane().add(glass);

    getContentPane().add(drawPanel);
}
```

Comment: Yes, i tried. Result was same. And Glass class already extends JPanel.

Comment: I actually meant, that you could try not use Glass but instead add the DrawingPanel to the Frame or Panel which you added the Glass Panel to. This way you would be painting the background image on the same JPanel which you also use for painting your rectangle.

Comment: I did what you recommended. Looks like now it doesn't even draw a rectangle, but mouse listeners are active and printing text to console on event.

Comment: @AlexandrZhukov `I did what you recommended` but you still haven't posted a `SSCCE` or `MCVE` that demonstrates the problem. We don't know the context of how the code you posted is actually used.